# Rspec - creating has_many records before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, associations

I am busy trying to factory up the relations I need for a test. 
we have a school which has many campus's.

```
class School
  has_many :campus
  ....
  validates :campus, presence: true
```

Although there is no mapping table, The campus has the school_id:

```
class Campus
  belongs_to :school
```

Now I have an egg and chicken situation here.

```
  school = School.new(name: "Hogwarts")
  campus = Campus.create(name: 'Griffendor', country_code: 7, school_id: school)
  school.save!
```

I cannot create a school until I have some campus's for it, and I can't create a school_id for campus because the school is not saved yet.

I tried specifying an id for the school in the creation process but it will ignore it and save the next available id. The system is using Rspec but for the life of me not using FactoryGirl.

Is there a quick fix for such a situation?

Comment: Me neither I was very surprised to see such a relationship, but it's working within the system. I think because they seeded the DB with all the schools. It seems like it would be impossible to ever add a new school.

Answer (score 1):

I'm so confused. As you can see from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association), the class that includes the `has_many` call is NOT the class with the foreign key.

[image: From the Active Record Guide]

But you have:

```
class School
  has_many :campus
  ...

  validates :campus, presence: true
end
```

What is it you think you're validating on school? I do believe you have it in the wrong place and that is the source of your heartache and sadness. So, move `validates:` to campus. This should allow you to do:

```
  school = School.create(name: "Hogwarts")
```

See if that does the trick.

Comment: It's a code base i was asked to help with. There are a number of really strange things happening here.

Comment: After you move `validates:`, what else is strange?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `validates :campus, presence: true`

School class must be:

```
class School
  has_many :campus
  ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
school = School.new(name: "Hogwarts")
campus = school.campus.build(name: 'Griffendor', country_code: 7)
school.save!
campus.save! # Not sure if it's necessary; you could also declare: has_many :campus, autosave: true
```

Comment: I get the following:
Failure/Error: campus = School.campus.build(name: 'Griffendor', country_code: 7)
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `campus' for #<Class:0x007f96bc6643d8>

Comment: I have just removed the validation.